# Syncing 3 threads sharing buffers using NSConditionLock. It's hard

Tags: objective-c, multithreading, xcode, macos

I have 3 threads (in addition to the main thread). The threads read, process, and write. They each do this to a number of buffers, which are cycled through and reused. The reason it's set up this way is so the program can continue to do the other tasks while one of them is running. So, for example, while the program is writing to disk, it can simultaneously be reading more data.

The problem is I need to synchronize all this so the processing thread doesn't try to process buffers that haven't been filled with new data. Otherwise, there is a chance that the processing step could process leftover data in one of the buffers.

The read thread reads data into a buffer, then marks the buffer as "new data" in an array. So, it works like this:

```
//set up in main thread
NSConditionLock *readlock = [[NSConditionLock alloc] initWithCondition:0];

//set up lock in thread
[readlock lockWhenCondition:buffer_new[current_buf]];

//copy data to buffer
memcpy(buffer[current_buf],source_data,data_length);

//mark buffer as new (this is reset to 0 once the data is processed)
buffer_new[current_buf] = 1;

//unlock
[readlock unlockWithCondition:0];
```

I use buffer_new[current_buf] as a condition variable to NSConditionLock. If the buffer isn't marked as new, then the thread in question will lock, waiting for the previous thread to write new data. That part seems to work okay.

The main problem is I need to sync this in *both directions*. If the read thread happens to take too long for some reason and the processing thread has already finished with processing all the buffers, the processing thread needs to wait and vice-versa.

I'm not sure NSConditionLock is the appropriate way to do this.

Comment: Yup.  Threading is hard.

Answer (score 2):

I'd turn this on its head.   As you say, threading is hard and multi-way synchronization of threads is even harder.   Queue based concurrency is often much more natural.

Define three queues;  a read queue, a write queue and a processing queue.   Then employ a rule stating that *no buffer shall be enqueued in more than one queue at a time*.

That is, a buffer may be enqueued onto the read queue and, once done reading, enqueued into the processing queue, and once done processing, enqueued into the write queue.

You could use a stack of buffers if you want but, typically, the cost of allocation is pretty cheap compared to the cost of processing and, thus, enqueue-for-read could also do the allocation while dequeue-once-written could do the free.

This would be pretty straightforward to code with GCD.   Note that if you really want parallelism, your various queues would really just be throttles, using semaphores -- potentially shared -- to enqueue the work to the global concurrent queues.

Note also that this design has a distinct advantage over what you are currently using in that it *uses no locks*.   The only locks are hidden below the GCD APIs as a part of queue management, but that is effectively invisible to your code.

Comment: I'd like to keep the code as portable as possible, hence the use of NSLocks/pthreads. What I ended up doing was using a combination of NSConditionLock and NSCondition. After a lot of testing, it seems to be working okay. It may be a little more tricky when porting to Linux using straight C, but at least I know it's possible since Cocoa's NSLocks use pthreads internally.

Answer (score 1):

Have you seen then [Apple Concurrency Programming Guide ?](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html)

It recommends several preferable methods for moving away from a Threads and Locks concurrency model. Using Operation Queues for example can not only reduce and simplify your code, speed up your development and give you better performance.

Sometimes you need to use threads, and you already have the correct idea. You will need to keep adding locks, and with each it will get exponentially more complicated until you can't understand your own code. Then you can start adding locks at random places. Then you're screwed.

Read the concurrency guide, then follow bbum's advice.

Comment: *... you can't understand your own code. Then you can start adding locks at random places. Then you're screwed.* Words of wisdom, that.